# Why am I getting multiple outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to write numbers into an textfile and output the number as an string but when I for example take the number 150 as an input I get multiple outputs.

**My output when taking the number 150 as an input:**

```
one
five
fifteen
fifty
one hundret and fifty
```

**My desired output when taking the number 150 as an input:**

`one hundret and fifty`

**My code:**

```
main_file = open('test.txt','w')
x = input("input your number")
                
main_file.write(x)
main_file.close()

with open(main_file) as f:
    datafile = f.readlines(1)
for line in datafile:
    if '1' in line:
        print("one")
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if '5' in line:
        print("five")
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if '15' in line:
        print("fifteen")
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if '50' in line:
        print("fifty")
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if '150' in line:
        print("one hundret and fifty")
```

**This is the value of my txt file:**

```
150
```

With that being said thank's to every one in advance who is able to help or has an suggenstion on how to fix this problem:)

Comment: all of your if statements are true, therefore they are printing their respective prints.

Comment: You could use module num2word. Install it by pip3 install num2word. use it like that: import num2word
print(num2word.word(1234567))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Scripter1**
Hey, this issue is happening because of the way you have framed your `if` conditions.
You need to understand the different types of conditional statements:

1. `If` - When you are using only `if` conditions, then the compiler will check whether it is `True or False` - If it is `True`, then it will execute the block of code defined inside it and move ahead.
2. `If - Else` - In this if the condition is `True` then it will execute the code inside `If` otherwise the block of code inside `else` would be executed
3. `If -Elif - Else` - This is the If-Else Ladder in which you define multiple conditions, and each condition would be checked **based on the order you have mentioned**. If all the conditions are wrong, then the `else` block of code would be executed.

- Here, If you see in your code. Since '150' have '1', '5', '15' as well along with '150' that's why you are getting multiple outputs.
- Since, the way you have written your conditions, I would like to suggest that start from the higher number (descending order) and make the conditions as `If-Elif-Else` and not `if` because even if you declare the conditions in descending order, you will get multiple outputs (since compiler will execute each and every `if` statement)

```py
    main_file = open('test.txt','w')
    x = input("input your number")
                    
    main_file.write(x)
    main_file.close()
    
    with open(main_file) as f:
        datafile = f.readlines(1)
    for line in datafile:
        if '150' in line:
            print("one hundred and fifty")
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        elif '50' in line:
            print("fifty")
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        elif '15' in line:
            print("fifteen")
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        elif '5' in line:
            print("five")
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        else:
            print("one")
```

- **But you can code this in a better way as well**, it will reduce the number of conditional statements you are including. Just check out, the modulo operator and how you can use it for reducing the number of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Question:
Is "5" in "150" -> Yes it is!

That causes your functions to trigger for every number that is found in your line.
It seems like you "hard coded" the answers for which case I would have used a dictionary to simplify the code and use less repetitions.

```py
numberToStringPairs = {"1":"one","2":"two",...,"150":"one hundred and fifty"}

for line in datafile:
    print(numberToStringPairs.get(line.strip()))
```

This follows the "hard coded" solution style you used. I first stripped the lines so that "1 " matches "1" too.
Your solution would have worked if you had used `if - elif` chained conditions with a direct comparison using `==`.

If you have any question, just comments under this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

All of your statements are evaluating to true, since for example '1', '5', '150' are a part of your lines. You will have to strict match using `==` instead of `in` for it to work.

Also, you will have to use else-if if you want only one of the if-statements to execute at a time.

Optimal code would look like:

```py
    ...

    if line.strip() == '1':
        # .strip() to remove \n from the end
        print("one")

    elif line.strip() == '5':
        # .strip() to remove \n from the end
        print("five")
    else:
        print("one hundret and fifty")

    ...
```